# Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function. react functional component

Tags: node.js, reactjs

**I extracted array from object by using results.post still it says data.map is not a function.**

```
       fetch('/allpost',{
      headers:{
        "Authorization":"Bearer "+localStorage.getItem("jwt")
      }
    }).then(res=>res.json())
    .then(result=>{
      console.log(result.posts)
      setData(result.posts)
    })  
  },[])
  return  (
    <div>
      {
        data.map(item=>{
          return(
            <div className='home-container'>
              <h5 className='home-name'>salil</h5>
              <div className='card-image-container'>
                <img className='card-image'  alt="blank" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506744038136-46273834b3fb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8d2FsbHBhcGVyJTIwbmF0dXJlfGVufDB8MHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" />
              </div>
              
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
      
     
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

can someone tell me whats the error I made here?

Comment: Could you please add the response data of ```result.posts``` ?

Comment: can you share the complete code of the component and are your sure you are getting `result.posts`

Comment: `fetch` is async process. Your `data.map` is already run before `fetch` data came. Because of that its crashing. You can do something like this `data && data.length>0 && your return code`

Comment: `data?.map` may be a viable option to try here.

Comment: The @ShubhamVerma answer is right, your app is trying to map a variable that is probably something you can´t map (like a string, boolean, number...). What you can do is using a ternary operator like `data?.length > 0? <Your Code /> : <p>"Loading..."</p>`. That is going to show a loading message while you get the data from your API... Another option could be initializing your data state with a [] -> `const [data, setData] = useState([])`

Comment: Just initialize the ```data``` variable with an empty array on state definition: ```const [data,setData] = useState([])```, or use map when you are sure: ```Array.isArray(data) && data.map(...```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

First, when the 'useState' is declared, should define the types and assignments. Like this `const [data,setData] = useState<Array<T>>([]);`.

---

Secondly, fetch api,we should confirm what type we want, like `.then(result=>{ setData(result?.posts || []); })`. that mean if 'result?.posts' is underfind, we can save [].

---

Finally, we should process the different types of data at render

```js
function _demo() {
    return (
      <div>
        {data?.length === 0 && (
          <div>
            <span>Loading, Please Wait</span>
          </div>
        )}
        
        {data?.length > 0 && data?.map((v)=> {
          return (
            <div>
            </div>
          )
        )}
      </div>
    );
}
```